# Creating dataframe from column names list and data which have blank spaces

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-api, google-finance

Using `GOOGLEFINANCE()` API on Python, I readback  `response` shown in attached snapshot. I would like to arrange this readback response as a dataframe.

Using the code below, I extract the `columns` and `data` from `response`. Do notice that `columns`, as well as, each row of `data` has a blank space as its first entry (marked with green arrows in the photo).
Next, when I try to make a dataframe `df`, I get error `AssertionError: 7 columns passed, passed data had 26 columns`

I think the first 'blank' data is causing some issue. Any suggestion how to overcome this?

**Code**:

```
response = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
        spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
        majorDimension='ROWS',
        range='Sheet1'
    ).execute()
columns = response['values'][1]
data = response['values'][2:]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
```

[image]

Comment: I think need to check if type of response['values'][2:] is list of all row entries

Comment: what is the type of data?

Comment: If it is ndarray, print its shape. If it is nested list print length of all the inner lists.